# How can I layout components like this?

Tags: java, blackberry, java-me

In BlackBerry (OS 6+), I need to have a layout like in the image below. But so far I have not been able to get the red-circled part right.

I used a `HorizontalFieldManager` and added the `BasicEditField` and two `ButtonFields` to it. But then only the `BasicEditField` is visible on-screen and the two buttons get pushed out of the screen (but still they are focusable, although not visible).

So any ideas anyone? Any help greatly appreciated!

The image (what I'm trying to do is circled in red):
[image]

Comment: check the extent of basic edit field......

Comment: @Nsr Sorry, I'm a bit new to BlackBerry development and can't understand what you meant :). So can you please be a bit more specific?

Comment: You don't see the buttons since`EditField` always consumes all available width. As Roshnal suggested, you can override its `sublayout()` method and limit its width.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this it is working.

```
HorizontalFieldManager manager = new HorizontalFieldManager(USE_ALL_WIDTH);
    BasicEditField editField = new BasicEditField("Test", ""){
        protected void layout(int width, int height) {
            super.layout(width, height);
            setExtent(140, getPreferredHeight());
        }
    };
    manager.add(editField);
    manager.add(new ButtonField("button1"));
    manager.add(new ButtonField("button2"));
    add(manager);
```

In above setExtent(width,height) method set the width according to your need.

Comment: In this specific case, I think you better use the same width for `super.layout()` and `setExtent()`.

Answer (score 2):

You can check the class `MyManager`. May be the same layout can be achieved with `HorizontalFieldManager`, but I failed several times when using `HorizontalFieldManager`.

```
public class MyScreen extends MainScreen {
    private BasicEditField _bef = new BasicEditField();
    private ButtonField _bf1 = new ButtonField("Button");
    private ButtonField _bf2 = new ButtonField("Button");

    public MyScreen() {
        MyManager mgr = new MyManager();
        _bef.setText("BasicEditField");
        mgr.add(_bef);
        mgr.add(_bf1);
        mgr.add(_bf2);
        add(mgr);
    }
}

class MyManager extends Manager {
    private final int HORIZONTAL_GAP = 5;

    public MyManager() {
        super(0);
    }

    protected void sublayout(int width, int height) {
        int fields = getFieldCount();
        Field field;
        int nHeight = 0;
        int remaininigWidth = width;
        int x0, x1, x2;

        // specific layout implementation only
        if (fields == 3) {
            // right most ButtonField
            field = getField(2);
            layoutChild(field, remaininigWidth, height);
            nHeight = Math.max(nHeight, field.getHeight()); 
            remaininigWidth -= (field.getWidth() + HORIZONTAL_GAP);
            x2 = remaininigWidth;

            // middle ButtonField
            field = getField(1);
            layoutChild(field, remaininigWidth, height);
            nHeight = Math.max(nHeight, field.getHeight()); 
            remaininigWidth -= (field.getWidth() + HORIZONTAL_GAP);
            x1 = remaininigWidth;

            // first BasicEditField
            field = getField(0);
            layoutChild(field, remaininigWidth, height);
            nHeight = Math.max(nHeight, field.getHeight());
            x0 = 0;

            setPositionChild(getField(0), x0, (nHeight - getField(0).getHeight()) / 2);
            setPositionChild(getField(1), x1, (nHeight - getField(1).getHeight()) / 2);
            setPositionChild(getField(2), x2, (nHeight - getField(2).getHeight()) / 2);

            setExtent(width, nHeight);
        } else {
            setExtent(width, 0);
        }

        field = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But what did you mean by "..but I failed several times"? So the above code has bugs or is it working? Thanks again!

Comment: When I have tried with `HorizontalFieldManager` it didn't work. But the above code segment is working. Just have a try.

Comment: It works, but the other answer is easier and smaller. So I'll choose that, but I gave +1 for you for giving a working answer quickly! Maybe you will want to take a look at the other answer? It uses a `HorizontalFieldManager`.

Comment: :), thank you. But above one is using some hard-coded values. If you use Torch or Storm and do a screen orientation change then the look may not adjusted automatically. Also depending on the text of Button 1 and 2 and the device screen size, the value of BasicEditField text needs to be changed. But the answer is a smart one.

Comment: True, but we can use some algorithm, like- get the screen width, divide by 4 and etc.. Then it won't be a problem about the BasicEditField size.

Comment: @Roshnal Good answer, though I would compact it slightly and remove some code. The correct solution would be to layout the buttons first (`layoutChild`) and only then layout the edit field. Lastly, all the fields should be positioned (`setPositionChild`). That's exactly what you did. For sure your answer is the most correct one.

Answer (score 1):

```
 HorizontalFieldManager hfm = new HorizontalFieldManager();
BasicEditField editField = new BasicEditField("", ""){
    protected void layout(int width, int height) {
        super.layout(100,  getPreferredHeight());
        setExtent(100, getPreferredHeight());
    }
};
hfm.add(editField);
hfm.add(new ButtonField("button1"));
hfm.add(new ButtonField("button2"));
add(hfm);
```